# Using this inside an Javascript IIFE within an object

Tags: javascript, object, iife

I would like to use `this` instead of the name of the object inside the IIFE.

```
var ops = {
   start: (function (){
      socket.on('set', function(data) { 
         ops.getData();             
    });
  }()),
  getData: function (){
      ... 
  }
};
```

How it can be done?

Comment: why is `start` an IIFE? This will execute the code when you define this object. `start` will be set to whatever `socket.on` returns

Comment: @Damon No it won't, since there's no `return` statement in the function. `start` will be set to `undefined`.

Comment: @Banzy That's beside the point, why would you want to set an object property to undefined as a side effect? The pattern here would normally be to define a start function on the object and call that function when appropriate, otherwise there is no reason to put that immediately executed block of code inside the object.

Comment: Yes @Damon it works fine now, but maybe it's better to change it as a regular function with a call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Not to mention that your function does not return anything to assign to `ops.start`.

```
var ops = {
  start: function (){
    var self = this;
    socket.on('set', function(data) { 
      self.getData();             
    });
  }
};

ops.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use getter and closure on your function context if needed. Getter automatically invokes a function:

```
var ops = {
   get start() {
      return socket.on('set', function(data) { 
         ops.getData();             
    });
  },
  getData: function (){
  }
};
```

Now you can just refer to ops.start

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new object and use it's prototype to access "this":

```
var o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  data: {
    value: 12
  },
  getobject: {
    get: function() {
      return this.data;
    }
  }
});

o.getobject;
```